# How to read multiple images in keras presented in a folder?

Tags: python-2.7, keras, keras-2

I want to read multiple images presented in folder and process them one after another continuously. I am using keras and theano as backend. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the size of the images? What model are you using? What errors do you encounter? What have you tried so far? Please give us some code.

Comment: My image file are in the folder data/train and i tried below code                          image_path='data/train'
numpy_int_array=np.array(image_path)
for i in numpy_int_array:
 input_im=image_path(i)

Answer (score 1):

Check the `flow_from_directory` from [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). There is a good example on this page that includes the use of data augmentation.